# Extract title of HTML page without loading entire page

Tags: html

I want to get a page's title with a script. The only solution I could come up with so far has the downside that it needs to load the entire page first, before it can start to `grep` for the `<title>`.

Since the title is always part of the `<head>`, it would make sense to stop loading the page as soon as there is a title being fetched.

How can I do this? I'm open for solutions in many languages.

Comment: you can specify to load only the first x bytes. pick a reasonable number and grep for `<title>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you could use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and limit the amount of bytes:

```
$file = file_get_contents('URL', FALSE, NULL, 0, x);  //Only load first x bytes
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $file, $matches);
$title = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Incidentally I was using `file_get_contents` already, but I didn't know about the other options it had.

Answer (score 0):

Given a supporting HTTP server, you can limit the amount of data you pull down with [content-range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) and hope that you pull down enough to reach the title element.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery .load()/.ajax() method

check [jQuery  .load() API reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax/load&redirect=no)